# Индексы минимальных значений с#

Tags: c#, массивы

Подскажите как найти индексы минимальных значений?
(если минимальных значений больше одного)Как вывести все индексы?
алгоритм поиска минимальных значений я сделал

```
using System;
class T5
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int value, index;
        int size = 155;
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int[] nums = new int[size];
        for (int k = 0; k < nums.Length; k++)
        {
            nums[k] = rnd.Next(1, 101);
            Console.Write(nums[k] + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        index = 0;
        value = nums[index];
        for (int k = 1; k < nums.Length; k++)
        {
            if (nums[k] < value)
            {
                value = nums[k];
                index = k;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Наименьшее значение: " + value);
        Console.WriteLine("Индекс элемента: " + index);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine("Индекс элемента: " + index); это и есть индекс минимального значения

Comment: Да, я запустил Ваш код, он мне корректно показал минимальный элемент и индекс минимального элемента. Написать код компактнее - конесно, можно, анпример, с помощью linq. Но работать - Ваш код вполне работает!

Comment: Используйте List<int> для индексов минимального значения, если находите новое значение, которое ещё меньше - очищаете List<int> и добавляете новое, если повтор - добавляете новый индекс в List<int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если минимальных значений больше одного, то собирайте их в список. Примерно так:

```
        index = new List<int>() {0};
        ...

        if (nums[k] < value)
        {
            value = nums[k];
            index = new List<int>() {k};
        }
        else if (nums[k] == value)
        {
            index.Add(k);
        }
```